# Getting an Error when creating a record

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, salesforce1-app

Getting an error when creating a new contact through a specific profile, If I logged in as an Admin, it worked fine, and I tried to look for the access but had no luck. The User has access to run the flow. Another thing that I have noticed in the User attempts to access the record, it shows the error
"Looks like there's a problem.
Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details.

The requested resource does not exist"
any suggestion how to nail down to issue. it definitely looks like access issue, but how to know for which field.[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled debug logs for an impacted user? Also, from the error message you've shown on creating the record, you've got a process builder or record triggered flow called Contact Create/Edit - Master' that you should be debugging.

Comment: I have tried with debug log but no success, and even I have tried deactivating the process flow, but still received the same error

Comment: If you are an admin user, then enable apex exception email. All uncaught exception from flows will get triggered to you. Then you can check which flow / flows, at what step is failing.

Comment: you most probably have a problem in your profile access on the object level. If the profile does not have rights on the object he will not be able to see the records. Additionally you may look into your sharing settings. As we don't know how your flow is configured, the user you are using may fail to have access to the newly created record and thus not be able to view it.